# Django - how to set regex when querying string

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have some string in database like this:

```
|pay_tocken                               |
|-----------------------------------------|
|d7fe6c3d52cab958a67d51a5f18a2288ad53c5ee |
|00684bf8e9af13e4345297725d2804e6d04158dc |
|851c4b07ab9954651f20871ed5574673e65ebe95 |
```

When I run a query to get it, it returns an error.

My query is:

```
def cart_items(request, tocken):
    pay = Pay.objects.get(pay_tocken=tocken)
    return render(request, 'pay/pay_items.html', {'pay':pay})
```

and url:

```
    from pay import views as pay_views
    url(r'^profile/product-items/(?P<tocken>\d+)/$', pay_views.cart_items, name="cart_items")
```

Template:

```
{% extends "store/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
     <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table-striped text-center">
          <tr>
              <th>Tockens</th>
          </tr>
            {% for payment in payments %}
          <tr>
              <td><a href="{% url 'cart_items' tocken=payment.pay_tocken %}">Tocken</a></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I run it, it returns an error:

> Reverse for 'cart_items' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'tocken': u'dfgdf'}' not found

Comment: Please Post your urls.py code and the HTML code from where you are calling this 'def cart_items'.

Comment: Your error doesn't happen in the code currently posted.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi added now

Comment: @Evert So what's this I see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using alphanumeric `tocken` but in url pattern you are matching to numerics only with `d+`. Change it to `w+` and it should work

```
url(r'^profile/product-items/(?P<tocken>\w+)/$', pay_views.cart_items, name="cart_items")
```